# Add new line to template for each item in a list

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

Given the following example list and Jinja template:

**List:**

```yaml
list:
    - foo
    - bar
```

**Jinja template:**

```yaml
{% for key in list %}
results:
      - "{{ key }}"
{% endfor %}
```

I am able to produce the following output:

```yaml
results:
    - foo
results:
    - bar
```

How can I instead append a line, for each item in the list, to the template to produce this result?

```yaml
results:
    - foo
    - bar
```

Is this possible with Ansible without using something like `lineinfile`? I am moreorless trying to replicate the [Helm range filter](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#looping-with-the-range-action) which might look like this:

```yaml
results:
    {{- range .Values.list }}
    - {{ . }}
    {{- end }}
```

---

The `join` filter appears to get me a little closer. For example:

```yaml
results:
    - "{{ list | join('\n- ') }}"
```

Produces the following. But it is not syntactically correct yet:

```yaml
results:
    - "foo
- bar"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the list

```yaml
list:
    - foo
    - bar
```

---

Q: ***"Produce this result!"***

```yaml
results:
    - foo
    - bar
```

A: There are more options:

1. You can iterate the list

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/test.yml
        content: |
          results:
          {% for key in list %}
              - {{ key }}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/test.yml 
results:
    - foo
    - bar
```

---

You can put the template into a file

```yaml
shell> cat templates/test.yml.j2
results:
{% for key in list %}
    - {{ key }}
{% endfor %}
```

Then, the *template* module gives the same result

```yaml
    - template:
        dest: /tmp/test.yml
        src: test.yml.j2
```

---

2. The next option is [Ansible formatting filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json) and Jinja *indent* filter. The task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/test.yml
        content: |
          results:
              {{ list|to_nice_yaml|indent(4) }}
```

3. You can use *tab* if you want to

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/test.yml
        content: |
          results:
          {% for key in list %}
          {{ '{}- {}'.format(tab, key) }}
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        tab: "{{ '\t' }}"
```

The tab spacing will depend on the pager

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/test.yml 
results:
    - foo
    - bar
```

Comment: `{{ list|to_nice_yaml|indent(4) }}` is beautiful! Much better than my abuse of the `join` filter. Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly, but I got it using the `join` filter and some escape sequences. This:

```yaml
results:
    - "{{ list | join('\"\n    - \"') }}"
```

Produces the following:

```yaml
results:
    - "foo"
    - "bar"
```

Dismantling that for clarity for the future Googlers....

`list | join('')` - Retrieve the variablized list and "join" them using the following delimiter sequence, which effectively introduces list items in a roundabout way

`\"` - Add a `"` character to the end of the item

`\n`     - Add a newline and tab in 4 spaces. *See footnote for more info.*

`- \"` - Add a new `- "` before adding each consecutive list item.

Not sure if it is possible to implement this without wrapping each templated list item in quotes or not. But that is syntactically correct so I will leave it.

*Footnote: If you use `\t` instead of adding whitespace characters, Ansible will throw the following error:*

> MSG:
>
> Error loading resource_definition: while scanning for the next token
> found character '\t' that cannot start any token