# Jinja2 Template "hosts.j2" Used to Create Hosts File on Each Node is Not Working

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I want to use a Jinja2 template to create hosts files on each of the nodes controlled by Ansible.

The template is named hosts.j2 and it consists of the following code:

```
{# This is the template for the /etc/hosts file #}
{% for host in groups['all'] %}
{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_facts']['default_ipv4']['address'] }} {{ inventory_hostname }}
{% endfor %}
```

The ansible playbook is:

```yaml
---
- name:  Deploy hosts files using a Jinja 2 template
  hosts:  all
  become:  true

  tasks:
    - name:  Create hosts files
      template:
        src: hosts.j2
        dest: /etc/hosts
        owner:  root
        group:  root
        mode:  "0644"
```

The playbook executes and the hosts files are created on each node, but for each unique IP address, the hostname is simply repeated for each unique IP address ie..,

192.xxx.xxx.xxx zoo1
192.xxx.xxx.xxy zoo1
...

On host2:

192.xxx.xxx.xxx zoo2
192.xxx.xxx.xxy zoo2

Can someone provide guidance on how to obtain the appropriate hostname for each unique IP address in each node's hostfiles?

Comment: Please format the question clearly, the ansible playbook is hard to read. as for the goal you are trying to achieve, I'm not sure if I got it right:  do you want the resulting hosts file to contain a table with one ip and hostname per line?

Comment: hello Grigory...yes...i would like he resulting hosts file to contain a table with one ip and hostname per line.

Comment: I'll re-input the ansible playbook...

Comment: This is the Jinja2 template:

Comment: have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74695589/add-new-line-to-template-for-each-item-in-a-list

Comment: Please don't ask for personal contact information. The whole idea of this site is that your question will be useful to other people, so both the question and the answer need to be available **here**. There is formatting help available in the editor; take the time to use it.

Answer (score 1):

There you go.

```
{%for host in groups['all']%}

{{hostvars[host]['ansible_facts']['default_ipv4']['address']}}
{{hostvars[host]['ansible_facts']['fqdn']}} {{hostvars[host]['ansible_facts']['hostname']}} 

{% endfor %}
```